# jstl c:out returns a "0" when I am trying to output a String (variable name containing a "-") defined as context-parameter in the web.xml

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have defined a context-param (in this case an URL) inside the J2EE Applicatons web.xml.
I am trying to output this URL as Link inside a JSP using the jstl (1.1) Taglibrary.
The Application is Java 1.4 based.

web.xml:

```
<web-app>
...
 <context-param>
   <param-name>my-url</param-name>
   <param-value>http://foo.bar.net/index.html</param-value>
 </context-param>
...
</web-app>
```

jsp:

```
  <c:out value="${my-url}">
```

Where the url should be a zero "0" ist outputtet.
I have also tried accessing the parameter with

```
  <c:out value="${contextParam.my-url}">
```

and

```
  <c:out value="${initParam.my-url}">
```

which leads to the same output.

Does anyone know how to correctly access a web.xml context-parameter from within
a jsp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initParam` is the correct thing to use, but the minus sign may be confusing it, and making it interpret it as an arithmetic expression, resulting in a zero.

Try this instead:

```
<c:out value="${initParam['my-url']}">
```